# subsetting pandas dataframe on specific date value

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
order_id buyer_id item_id                time        
537       79      93 2016-01-04 10:20:00    
540      191      93 2016-01-04 10:30:00    
556      251      82 2016-01-04 13:39:00  
589      191     104 2016-01-05 10:59:00   
596      251      99 2016-01-05 13:48:00    
609       79     106 2016-01-06 10:39:00    
611      261      97 2016-01-06 10:50:00   
680       64     135 2016-01-11 11:58:00  
681      261     133 2016-01-11 12:03:00    
682      309     135 2016-01-11 12:08:00
```

I want to subset this dataframe on `date == '2016-01-04`.Datatypes of `df` dataframe are

`df.dtypes
Out[1264]: 
order_id             object
buyer_id             object
item_id              object
time         datetime64[ns]`

This is what I am doing in python

```
df[df['time'] == '2016-01-04']
```

But it returns me an empty dataframe. But,when I do 
`df[df['time'] < '2016-01-05']` it works. Please help

Comment: You can use `df.loc[df['time'].isin(['2016-01-04'])]`

Comment: @jezrael But, why it doesn't work with `df[df['time']=='2016-01-04']` ?

Comment: The problem here is that the comparison is being made against an exact value, as none of the times are `00:00:00` then no matches occur

Comment: You could do something like this: `df[df['time'].dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04').date()]` so this would strip the time components so you're only comparing dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the comparison is being performed for an exact match, as none of the times are `'00:00:00'` then no matches occur, you'd have to compare just the date components in order for this to work:

```
In [20]:
df[df['time'].dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04').date()]

Out[20]:
   order_id  buyer_id  item_id                time
0       537        79       93 2016-01-04 10:20:00
1       540       191       93 2016-01-04 10:30:00
2       556       251       82 2016-01-04 13:39:00
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No worries, semantically the partial comparison failure is correct behaviour, it would still be nice to do partial comparisons as this is a common use case

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [DatetimeIndex Partial String Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing):

```
print df
   order_id  buyer_id  item_id                time
0       537        79       93 2016-01-04 10:20:00
1       540       191       93 2016-01-04 10:30:00
2       556       251       82 2016-01-04 13:39:00
3       589       191      104 2016-01-05 10:59:00
4       596       251       99 2016-01-05 13:48:00
5       609        79      106 2016-01-06 10:39:00
6       611       261       97 2016-01-06 10:50:00
7       680        64      135 2016-01-11 11:58:00
8       681       261      133 2016-01-11 12:03:00
9       682       309      135 2016-01-11 12:08:00

df = df.set_index('time')
print df['2016-01-04']
                     order_id  buyer_id  item_id
time                                            
2016-01-04 10:20:00       537        79       93
2016-01-04 10:30:00       540       191       93
2016-01-04 13:39:00       556       251       82
```

Comment: is it possible to produce same results without datetime as an index?